# CloudKit app data not displaying in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, cloudkit

My predicate/query/performquery code is in working order, my table cell is set up with the right tablecell controller and reusable identifier, I have abstracted the nameLabel from the valueForKey of my CKRecordType and have not been able to load/view the updated UI.

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class table: UITableViewController {
var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

    func fetch()
    {   
    categories = []  
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            for result in results!
            {
              self.categories.append(result)
            }
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock( { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData() 
            })
        }
        self.fetch()      
}
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.categories.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining") as! tablecell
    let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String 
    return cell
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 }
```

here is the actual project if more info is needed: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/twt20r0sdauglhs/AAB6Y2CcxpT1hp0mBE_Znzgya?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

After re-visiting some older code, I was able to figure out that I needed to set my categories variable to

```
var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []
```

as well as rearrange some of the brackets in my fetch function.  I needed to place the calling of the fetch function outside the function (silly mistake) and finally close the viewdidload method after calling fetch().

```
   func fetch()
    {    
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dining", predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        else
        {
            for result in results!
            {
              self.categories.append(result)
            }

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock( { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        }
}
     fetch()   
}
```